# .CSV file write by line, checking for errors

Tags: c#, file, csv

first question so hopefully it'll be relevant. While not terribly new to coding... I'm pretty new to 'Good' coding so apologies if I'm completely unaware of obvious best practice.

I'm currently writing to a CSV file by row (using c#).

Which was all well and good till i got told this morning, that the department i'm writing the code for actually want all the lines in one file (i was doing a file per batch, and error checking on a batch lvl, so if anything was wrong with the batch none of the batch was exported)

They still need it to be all or nothing on a batch lvl (and i'm checking the 'cell' values before trying to write them to file, so that stage should work) but I'm acutely aware that the one part of my code which i currently can't check works before beginning the file write is the line writes themselves. And I was wondering how likely it is for individual lines to fail to write?,  assuming the file is created properly/ accessed properly for the first line?
and i guess secondly if this is likely to be a problem, is there any 'best practice' I should be aware of to easy(or eliminate) the problem.

code below which i call for each row in the batch that needs writing.

```
public void WriteRow(CsvRow row)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        bool firstColumn = true;
        foreach (string value in row)
        {
            // Add separator if this isn't the first value
            if (!firstColumn)
                builder.Append(',');
            // Implement special handling for values that contain comma or quote
            // Enclose in quotes and double up any double quotes
            if (value.IndexOfAny(new char[] { '"', ',' }) != -1)
                builder.AppendFormat("\"{0}\"", value.Replace("\"", "\"\""));
            else
                builder.Append(value);
            firstColumn = false;
        }
        row.LineText = builder.ToString();
        WriteLine(row.LineText);
    }
```